# Static List with open hashing C

Tags: c, hash

Im a begginer developer and i need help!
I have a txt file of 2287 lines
Contains ID (int), Name (string), Number1, Number2, Number3 (all 3 floats).

"

1234 Jose 10 11 12

...

...

"

I need to get the data from this file and implement a Hash table in separate chain WITH static list.
Also needs to have Insert, Remove and Search functions.

I have so many problems until now.
I dont know how to put it with a static list, and before that i cant hash it properly, its all NULLs..
Anyone can help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 2287




int main(){


    FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen("dados.txt","r");
        if (fp==NULL){
            printf("Erro na abertura\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
            }


             struct aluno{
                int matricula;
                char nome[30];
                float n1,n2,n3;
                struct aluno *next;
                };
            struct aluno aluno[max];
            struct aluno *hash[max];

//povoando com os dados
    int i=0;

    
    for(i=0;i<max;i++){
        fscanf(fp,"%d %s %f %f %f\n", &aluno[i].matricula, &aluno[i].nome, &aluno[i].n1, &aluno[i].n2, &aluno[i].n3);
    }

    //teste pra ver se o fscanf funcionava
    printf("%s %d %f" , aluno[3].nome, aluno[2].matricula, aluno[1].n1);



    void inicializa()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
        hash[i] = NULL;
}


    void insere(int valor){
        //cria a newAluno com o valor
        struct aluno *newAluno = malloc(sizeof(struct aluno));
        newAluno->matricula = valor;
        newAluno->next = NULL;

        //calcula a chave hash
        int chave = valor % max;

        //checa se esta null
        if(hash[chave] == NULL)
            hash[chave] = newAluno;

        else{

            struct aluno *temp = hash[chave];

            while(temp->next){
                temp = temp->next;
                }

            temp->next = newAluno;
        }
    }

    int busca(int valor){
        int chave = valor % max;
        struct aluno *temp = hash[chave];
        while(temp){
            if(temp->matricula == valor)
                return 1;
            temp = temp->next;
    }



    return 0;
    }

    void print(){


    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        struct aluno *temp = hash[i];
        printf("hash[%d]-->",i);
        while(temp)
        {
            printf("%d -->",temp->matricula);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
        }
    }

print();
 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually i know why thats all NULLS, because i was not running the insert (yeah, im that kind of begginer)

Comment: plz format code properly, look at other properly formatted [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209931/how-to-use-inner-loop-to-find-all-prime-numbers-from-1-to-a-user-input-number)